# toggle image in imageview on double tap

Tags: android, image

i want to toggle image in imageview, i have tried several methods and failed.. 
this is the code..

there are 2 problems..
1) the on click listner is faulty..
2) the condition if(image.isClickable()) is always false

this is the code..

```
@Override
public void onDoubleTap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      flip();
}
public void flip()
{
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(image.isClickable())
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.highmaths);
            else
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lowmaths);
        }
    });
}
```

now i am having the following error in the on click listener..

```
 The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View 
 is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})
```

but when i hide it, app runs but the condition(image.isClickable()) will always be false..

Comment: why do you need to implement the `isClickable()` anyway? you are just trying to swap the images on the `DoubleTap` Gesture right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK try this

First you need a boolean to determine which image is there

```
Boolean flag = false;
```

Then implement `onDoubleTap()` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    if(flag){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.highmaths);
        flag=false;
    }else{
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lowmaths);
        flag=true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: sure buddy.. just a coupla queries .. whats wrong with the on click?? also can we chk which image the double tap is happening on ??

Comment: why would you implement the `onClickable()` anyway? you wanted to swap the images in the **DoubleTap** and it is done. why mess with other methods and properties which are not related to the task and lead to confusion.