# i want to change the image when i click on a check box

Tags: android, checkbox

I want that when I click first time on this check box it should change the image from my Image View and when I click again on same checkbox it should change the image in Image View with another Image.

I Tried:-

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         if(isChecked){
             myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.saveimage);
         }else{
             myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deleteimage);
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: CHECK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942116/state-checked-doesnt-toggle-imageview-on-and-off/34020870#34020870

Comment: What's going wrong with your current code?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: replace your code with myImage.setImageResource();

Comment: @Michael Dodd and Rohit5k2 it's not showing any error, when i select checkbox first time it' set a image in my image view but when i click on it again it's not doing anything

Comment: Check these link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850354/toggle-image-in-imageview-on-double-tap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193167/change-source-image-for-image-view-when-pressed/22476407

Comment: @Chirag Savsani thank you so much, it's done thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome, that answer is posted by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done:-

Take globally (boolean switchStatus = false);

```
if(switchStatus == true){
    dialog.dismiss();
    image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_delete);
    switchStatus = false;
}else{
    dialog.dismiss();
    image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_checkmark);
    switchStatus = true;
}
```

Comment: This code can be simplified. Use `if (switchStatus) {`, and after the end of the `if/else` statement use `switchStatus = !switchStatus` to flip its value instead of manually setting to `true` or `false`. Would you like me to edit your answer with this simplification?

Comment: (Truth be told this can also be reduced to just 3 lines of code using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), but that might be a bit too advanced for the scope of this question)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code apart from the lack of using setchecked method. When you check your chechbox , call `checkbox.setchecked(true)` and when you unckeck it, call `checkbox.setchecked(false)`;

Answer (score 0):

Because your image is in Drawable I think you should try this:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         if(isChecked){
             myImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.saveimage,getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
         }else{
             myImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.deleteimage,getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
         }
     }
 });
```